# Buffering in a Windowed Kafka Streams App

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, apache-kafka-streams

In our application, we are seeking to take JSON messages from an input topic, combine them in a given window and write them out to the destination topic. `mergeJsonNodes` is the function responsible for simply merging two JSON objects.

```
KStream<String, JsonNode> transformed = datastreamSource
  .groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), JSON_SERDE))
  .windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(60 * 1000))
  .reduce((a, b) -> mergeJsonNodes(a, b))
  .toStream((windowedKey, node) -> windowedKey.key());
```

We have successfully deployed this in several of our non production environments.  However, when we moved to production, where the volume on the input topic (`datastreamSource`) is much greater, we ran into a bottleneck that we are seeking to understand.

What we see is that our streams app is making slow progress on the source topic, and is committing to the destination topic ~once every minute.  However, it is ingesting from the input topics too slowly to keep up with our production traffic committing to that topic.  We are migrating from a non windowed, non grouped streams application that has been performing well for many months.

The resources on the host for the Kafka streams app do not appear to be constrained; it is not the case that the app is lacking in memory or disk.

Our question is what other factors, specifically configuration settings, we might be able to modify to allow a streams app to pull more messages off of the input topic at a time.  It appears that our app is somehow limited in its ability to continue reading from the source top
ic.

Two that jumped out at us initially from [the docs](https://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html):
* `buffered.records.per.partition`
* `cache.max.bytes.buffering`

Does anyone have experience with high throughput windowed streams apps that could provide any pointers?  Thanks!!

Comment: You should figure out what the bottleneck is. What is your target load? Is your network saturated? How many input topic partitions do you have? How many threads/instances you do run?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know particularly in windowed aggregation but when aggregating in Kafka streams you have 2 configuration to look out that handle how the aggregate processor node will cache message before flushing to the state store and sending result aggregate records to downstreams processors : `cache.max.bytes.buffering`, `commit.interval.ms`.

You have the consumer config that you can adjust in kafka streams : `poll.ms`.

You can scale your app too, how many partitions have your input topic ? It will lead to the number of task processing your input topic and thus influence the scalability of your app.

More partitions means more tasks means more consumers means more instances or even more threads on instances, (check `num.streams.thread`).

Hope that's help.